# Database url on local server

Tags: mysql, jdbc, phpstorm

I'm using xampp installation of apache 2.4, php 5.5 and MySql 5.6 on win 8.1 64bit machine.
I need to find out my database url, and what jdbc driver files should I use to connect to database through phpstorm 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database url will be whatever XAMPP sets it to, by default it's on `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` using port 3306

As far as the JDBC driver, probably best to just use the [JDBC Connector](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

Your JDBC URL should look like this: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<schema_name>`

Just replace  with your intended schema and you should be set.

Comment: @user3119997 No prob, glad to help! Also marking an answer as correct is the normal method of confirming the answer is what solved your problem.